# Parsing UI feedback

Tags: android, user-interface, android-parser

In my application I have to parse a big object which has other parcelable things inside so it takes some time 1-2 secs.

I would like to implement UI feedback for the time needed by the application to parse my object, but have no idea how to do it. How do I present a statusbar or something while the parsing is ongoing ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Implement some logic for displaying spinner or some loading icon and display it while you're waiting for the object to parse.

```
showSpinner();
Object object = Object.parse(value);
hideSpinner();
```